# background-image property can't be changed by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background-image

Like the title say, for some reason my function don't want to perform a change to the `background-image` property. I also made the function change the `background-color` to check if it is working and it does. So it seems that the problem is not in the syntax.

```js
function feedSlide () {
  var x = [
    '../img/feed1.png', 
    '../img/feed2.png', 
    '../img/feed3.png',
    '../img/feed4.png'
  ];
  var y = ['green', 'red', 'blue', 'yellow'];
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(z) { return function() { 
      console.log(x[z]); 
      $('#feedback').css({"background-image" : "url(" + x[z] + ")"});
      $('#feedback').css({"background-color" : y[z] });
    }; }(i), 1000*i);
  }
}
```

```css
#feedback {
  width: 400px;
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="aboutDiv">
  <div id="feedback"></div>
  <div id="audio"></div>
</div>
```

I'm on that for hours now and everything seems to be changeable but the `background-image`. Any information is very welcome.

Comment: The background image is added -> https://jsfiddle.net/a2schxaj/ Is the image location correct?

Comment: You need to actually call your `feedSlide` function. This can be done by adding `$(feedSlide);` to your js.

Comment: Check the network tab of the browser for an 404s

Comment: It would be much cleaner to do this using addClass/removeClass rather than manipulating styles directly

Comment: In addition to @Morpheus comment - note that background-image paths are relative to the path of the current page.  if you're using url redirects (eg [tag:ASP.Net-mvc] then it may not be where you're expecting it to be.

Comment: In addition to @Callam comment - the background-image in a css file is relative to the path of the .css file, so will not depend on the url of the current page (unless you use inline styles).  Using css classes is generally better practice and allows you to transitions etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. @Morpheus: The image location is definitely correct. @Olian04: The function is called, the happening of `background-color` change tells me that. @freedom-m: I used the same path i would use, when I call the url from my stylsheet and yeah, I will try the add/removeClass think. I wanted to avoid it because its less elegant when you have many pictures.

Comment: I also tryed using a css animation, which worked but for some reason the timing of the first change was always to early and if you want to add another animation on opacity to add some fades between the pictures, that solution is out.

Comment: @Raphi `I used the same path i would use, when I call the url from my stylsheet` is your stylesheet in the same folder with the javascript file?

Comment: no its in a folder called css. Javascript is in a folder called js

Answer (score 0):

After every attempt to solve this problem failed, I found the solution in a CSS animation.

```
 #feedback {
  height: 110px;
  width: 380px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  animation-name: feedSlide;
  animation-duration: 40s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
 }  

@keyframes feedSlide {
 0.00% {background-image: url(../img/feed1.png); opacity: 0;}
 3% {opacity: 1;}
 22% {opacity: 1;}
 25% {background-image: url(../img/feed1.png); opacity: 0;}
 26% {background-image: url(../img/feed2.png); opacity: 0;}
 29% {opacity: 1;}
 47% {opacity: 1;}
 50% {background-image: url(../img/feed2.png); opacity: 0;}
 51% {background-image: url(../img/feed3.png); opacity: 0;}
 54% {opacity: 1;}
 72% {opacity: 1;}
 75% {background-image: url(../img/feed3.png); opacity: 0;}
 76% {background-image: url(../img/feed4.png); opacity: 0;}
 79% {opacity: 1;}
 97% {opacity: 1;}
 100% {background-image: url(../img/feed4.png); opacity: 0;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below code,

```
function feedSlide () {
  var x = [
    'feed1.png', 
    'feed2.png', 
    'feed3.png',
    'feed4.png'
  ];
  var y = ['green', 'red', 'blue', 'yellow'];
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(z) { return function() { 
      console.log(x[z]); 
      var element = document.getElementById('#feedback');
      element.style.backgroundImage = "url('img/" + x[z] + "')";
      element.style.backgroundColor = y[z];
    }; }(i), 1000*i);
  }
}
```